# How to interpret "Image.fromarray()" method?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create an image from "numpy.ndarray", using the following:

`x = np.random.randint(0, 256, (3, 64, 64), dtype=np.uint8)`

`y = Image.fromarray(x)`

However, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 64), |u1

But when passing "x" as such:

`x = np.random.randint(0, 256, (64, 64, 3), dtype=np.uint8)`

`y = Image.fromarray(x)`

It works. But from what I understand: `np.random.randint(low, high, (depth/layers, rows, columns))`. Therefore, the first "x" makes sense, as it has 3 layers of a (64x64) matrix; while the latter represents 64 layers of a (64x3) matrix.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Image requires "channels last" arrays as images. Your first example has the color channels at its first axis. Although the poor documentation in PIL docs does not help, as it is not stated clearly.

For more about the conecpt of channel first or channel last images, see [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-channels-first-and-channels-last-image-formats-for-deep-learning/).